# Pass pk into another template in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

So basically what I want to do is by using a generated link with the pk:

lets say `127.0.0.0:8000/27/`

Get access to that pk for use it in another template with an if statement
for example:

```
{% for book in Books %}
{% if book.pk == category.pk %}
     <!-- Generate some HTML here-->
```

In my project I generate the links by passing the pk of an object as a variable for example:

```
{% for category in Categories %}
<a href="{{ category.pk }}">
```

in my main urls.py:

```
...
path('<int:pk>/',v.BookList.as_view(slug="pk")),
...
```

in my app/views.py:

```
class BookList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
login_url = 'accounts/login/'

template_name = 'ListsViews/BookList.html'
model = Book
context_object_name = "Books"
slug = "pk"

def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    return queryset.get(slug=self.slug)
```

in app/models.py

```
class Category(models.Model)
    book_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        default=_lazy('Tech'),
        choices=Grade
    )

class Book(models.Model)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    book_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=10,
        default=_lazy('Learn Python'),
        choices=Grade
    )
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. It does't make sense to write `{% if book.pk == category.pk %}`. Just because a book and a category have the same primary key doesn't mean they are related.

Comment: What I meant is that wanted to add the "book" to a list only if it's from that "category", the thing is that categories list is a diferent template and books is another, so I though I could compare the ID's to make sure that the book belongs to that category.

Comment: We can't tell how a book links to a category because you haven't shown your models.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `pk` from the URL with `self.kwargs['pk']`. A list view does not have a `get_object` method - you should override `get_queryset` instead.

```
class BookList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    login_url = 'accounts/login/'

    template_name = 'ListsViews/BookList.html'
    model = Book

    context_object_name = "books"  # NB Usual style in Django is lowercase books instead of Books

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(BookList, self).get_queryset().filter(category=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

That means your queryset will only contain books from that category, so you don't have to check the category in the template.

```
{% for book in books %}
  {{ book }}
{% endfor %}
```

I don't see the need for `slug="pk"` in the view or in  `v.BookList.as_view(slug="pk")`, so I would remove it.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<int:pk>/',v.BookList.as_view()),
    ...
]
```